# Spring @Value default value for String[]

Tags: java, spring, annotations

I'm wondering how I can set a default Value for String[].

```
@Value("${blacklist}")
private String[] blacklist;
```

In runtime the list is filled via my application.yml. In Testcases it is `null` and I will not set any value for each Testcase. 
Furthermore if there are no entries in die application.yml it have to be an empty array.

Usage:

```
for (String varToRemove : blacklist) {
        vars.remove(varToRemove );
 }
```

Pls no answers like "Why you do not just null-check it?". I want to know how to set the default value :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was so concentrated on the Annotation that I forgot the simplest way (and it works):

```
@Value("${blacklist:}")
private String[] blacklist= new String[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
@Value("#{blacklist ?: '1,2,3'}")
```

Taken from: https://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-value-default-value/

Comment: Found this page too, but didn't work for me. But look, I've found the answer!

Comment: Do you have a property named 'blacklist'? Is your class a spring component/service ?

Comment: Yes I have this property. And I found already the solution. Pls see my answer below.